# Button to replace a switch

Tags: ios, swift, button, click, uiswitch

I have a table view controller consisting of a list of colors. I want the user to be able to star which colors he or she likes the most. I currently am using switches to do this, but I want something more visually appealing. I think a button might work. However, I want the button to have similar properties to the switch (ex: isOn property). How might I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIButton`s **also have a switch like functionality**.

In IB, set a different image in Interface Builder for the "Selected State Configuration".

Then, add this in your `@IBAction` of your button (where "button" is the name of your button):

```
self.button.selected = !self.button.selected
```

Comment: I realized this after I asked the question. This is the simplest solution and accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's why subclassing exists.  Here is an **untested** example:

```
class StarButton : UIButton {

    override var isSelected: Bool {

        willSet {

            let image = UIImage(named: newValue ? "FilledStar" : "EmptyStar")
            self.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the accessoryType property of the tableviewcell. You can set it to .checkmark

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
}
```

This will look like the image below
[image]